# Run asp.net 4.5 in Docker

Tags: docker

I have one project base on asp.net 4.5, now I want run it in Docker. As far as I am known, only asp.net 5 be supported this moment, so has any way let me run my project in Docker?

Answer (score 2):

You must read [Mono documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/) about ASP.NET MVC Support. Mono can handle  your needs, running under Docker Linux Containers.
Using Windows Containers (new feature becomes with Windows Server 2016) you will do that without any trick.
About Mono and Docker, that was useful, stable and can solve your requirements, depends exclusivelly what you are using in your project to understand that is compactible with mono runtime.

[Mono Docker repository on Github](https://github.com/mono/docker)

[Mono on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mono/)

Enjoy and tell us about your experiences.

Comment: Docker engine support is also available on Windows 8, Windows 10, Win Server 2012 and 2016, with full stack support for .net and SQL Server, from windocks.com

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches depending on whether you want to run Linux or Windows containers. For Linux containers, you'd have to port your app to Mono, as laid out by @luiz-carlos-faria

To run in Windows Docker containers, you'd have to create a 4.6/4.5 base image similar to this one: https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/master/windows-container-samples/windowsservercore/dotnet35/Dockerfile

You can run that on Windows Server 2016 TP5 (free download) in a VM.